# How to implement custom API keys using Okta

Tags: api, authorization, okta

I am looking for instructions to implement API keys to protect an API using Okta.

The idea is similar to the GitHub Personal Access Tokens workflow.

The frontend application will have the access token to unblock access to the BFF.

It is not per end-user auth but about access tokens between applications ( App-2-App authorization, as opposed to End-User-2-App authentication? If that makes sense ).

Thanks,
André

Answer (score 0):

You can register an OIDC application with `client_credentials` OIDC flow, which will allow that application to use client id/secret pair to get an OAuth access token to call your API. It's exactly for your use case of some system app/account to get a JWT to call back-end services